# River rapids list and coordinates

Tags: data-request, geospatial, global

Are there any sources of spatial information about river rapids worldwide (with difficulty category)?

Comment: Difficulty to do what?

Comment: I mean something like "Class" column at [this table](https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/River/state-summary/state/CO/).

Comment: so you mean difficulty/class for canoeists to traverse?

Comment: Exactly. But it looks like such sources exist maximum for selected countries level (for example Russia or USA). To be honest i thought that exploring different countries rivers is more popular between canoeists.

Answer (score 2):

American Whitewater offers the **[National River Database](https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/River/view/)**.

> The river list selection page gives an overview of real-time information that we can track on a state-by-state basis. We track information for the United States, Canada, Mexico, the Dominican Republic and Costa Rica.

Data is mostly from gauge and user reports. An example of a gauge page looks like this

https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/Gauge2/detail/id/3358/

I don't see an export option, but if you contact them and have good motives, then maybe they can help. Otherwise, the HTML is easy enough to "parse".

[image]

---

As for the "difficulty", the state pages have a table with the Class.

https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/River/state-summary/state/WI/

And individual rivers have more info

https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/River/detail/id/2754/

Including some geo-info

https://www.americanwhitewater.org/content/River/detail/id/2754/#tab-directions

[image]